# Azure Managed Identity - credential rollover Info

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

1. How often are credentials rotated in managed identity?
2. Could the automatic rotation of credentials for MSIs potentially
   affect the application? a. Does the application need to be restarted
   after an automatic rotation of credentials in order to be able to
   connect to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How often are credentials rotated in managed identity?*

The smallest credential rotation period for a managed identity is `45 days`. That said, credential rotation is controlled by the resource provider that hosts the Azure resource. It's up to the resource provider to call for new credentials, so the resource provider could wait longer than 45 days. Note that the credential is no longer valid for token acquisition after 90 days, so the resource provider must request a new credential before then.

*Could the automatic rotation of credentials for MSIs potentially affect the application? a. Does the application need to be restarted after an automatic rotation of credentials in order to be able to connect to the database?*

The credential rotation is opaque to the application running on the VM. The application does not need to be restarted when the credential rotates. Unrelated to credential rotation, the application does need to acquire a new Azure AD token when the token it is using has expired.

Comment: Interesting, [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#credential-rotation) says `46` days is default. Do you know where it says minimum is `45` days?