# Does managed Identity rotation affects role assignments and access policies

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I have created a user-managed-identity in my App Service and using it for accessing 2 services:

1. Key Vault: Added access policies in Key Vault for this identity to access secrets.
2. ACR: Added ACR pull role assignment in container registry for container image pull in app service.

Now my confusion is, when Azure does the managed identity rotation behind the scenes, does it automatically also update the access policies and assignments too, i am hoping that it should else there is not point of having a wrapper over Service Principal. But please let me know your thoughts around this, I am pretty new to the Azure identities concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more details about `Azure does the managed identity rotation`?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, azure manages the identity the user doesn't have to rotate the keys, something which was needed for service principal. And as per the stackoverflow thread, its minimum duration is 45 or 46 days.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766916/azure-managed-identity-credential-rollover-info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An identity has secrets, which need to be rotated often. In the case of the Azure Managed identities, these secrets are rotated by Azure itself: so that you don't have to deal with storing them securely or rotating them often.

You have assigned the identity to KeyVault and ACR policies. When the identity secrets are rotated, the identity itself does not change. So it will continue to have access to KeyVault and ACR, even after its secrets are rotated.  So you don't need to worry about anyone needing to update the access polices or assignments.